# How to split tokens, count number of tokens, and write in a file in python?

Tags: python-2.7, count, split, token

I have file which has data in lines as follows:

```
    ['Marilyn Manson', 'Web', 'Skydera Inc.', 'Stone Sour', 'The Smashing Pumpkins', 'Warner Bros. Entertainment','This is a good Beer]
    ['Voices Inside', 'Expressivista', 'The Kentucky Fried Movie', 'The Bridges of Madison County']
```

and so on. I want to re-write the data into a file which has lines with tokens with words less than 3 or some other number. e.g.:

```
    ['Marilyn Manson', 'Web', 'Skydera Inc.', 'Stone Sour']
    ['Voices Inside', 'Expressivista']
```

this is what I have tried so far:

```
for line in open(file):
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.rstrip()
    prog = re.compile("([a-z0-9]){32}")

     if line:
        line = line.replace('"', '')
        line = line.split(",")
        if re.match(prog, line[0]) and len(line)>2:
           wo=[]
           for words in line:
              word=words.split()
              if len(word)<3:
                  print word.append(word)
```

But the output says None. Any thoughts where I am making a mistake?

Comment: `print word.append(word)` - haven't read the whole program, but this part makes no sense. First, `word.append(word)` appends a list to itself; did you mean to append to something else? Second, `append` returns `None`. Why are you printing this?

Comment: @user2357112 I was trying to write it to a file but before that I wanted to see if what I am writing was correct or not, which turned out to be not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to do what you're doing is to use `ast.literal_eval`, which automagically converts string representations of Python objects (e.g. lists) into actual Python objects.

```
import ast

# raw data
data = """
['Marilyn Manson', 'Web', 'Skydera Inc.', 'Stone Sour', 'The Smashing Pumpkins', 'Warner Bros. Entertainment','This is a good Beer']
['Voices Inside', 'Expressivista', 'The Kentucky Fried Movie', 'The Bridges of Madison County']
"""
# set threshold number of tokens
threshold = 3
# split into lines
lines = data.split('\n')
# parse non-blank lines into python lists
lists = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in lines if line]
# for each list, keep only those tokens with less than `threshold` tokens
result = [[item for item in lst if len(item.split()) < threshold]
          for lst in lists]
# show result
for line in result:
    print(line)
```

Result:

```
['Marilyn Manson', 'Web', 'Skydera Inc.', 'Stone Sour']
['Voices Inside', 'Expressivista']
```

I think the reason your code isn't working is that you're trying to match `line[0]` against your regex `prog` - but the problem is that `line[0]` isn't 32 characters long for either of your lines, so your regex won't match.